# How to create a JavaScript animation loop that stops when another starts playing?

Tags: javascript, animation

How to create an animation loop that spins for a while and calls another animation, and when another animation starts working, the first one waits for the other to finish, and when the other animation has finished its work, the first one starts playing again, and so on in a circle. As I understand it, it is problematic to do this through setTimout(in recursion), since they overlap each other and cannot wait for the completion of the other.
That's what I tried to do:

```js
var func = function(i) {

  return function() {

    if (i >= 5) return;
    console.log("turn no. " + i);

    // running second recursion 
    var func2 = function(i_) {

      return function() {
        if (i_ >= 75) return;
        console.log("turn no2. " + i_);

        if (i_ >= 75) {
          console.log('2 Player won');
        } else {
          setTimeout(func2(++i), 2000);
        }

      }
    }
    setTimeout(func2(0), 2000);
    // end running second recursion

    if (i >= 5) {
      console.log('1 Player won');
    } else {
      setTimeout(func(++i), 100);


    }

  }
}

setTimeout(func(0), 100);
```

Comment: Save the return of 'setTimeout' and clear it with 'clearTimeout'.

Comment: @jjuniob yes it worked, thanks a lot)